# Make Windows enter BIOS on start screen per default, without key combination?

Tags: windows, boot, bios, multi-boot

How can I achieve the question in the title?
I need this because I have a dual partition Windows and Ubuntu 18.04. and I can't set Ubuntu to be the default OS on start-up. Furthermore, the bios key combination `fn+F7` works only 1/5 of the times on start-up, mostly it just gets ignored and Windows gets loaded.

Comment: You need to identify the specific hardware you're dealing with - the fact that you mention an fn key indicates you're probably using a laptop.

Comment: Yes, I am on a laptop, but I thought this shouldn't make a difference. I am using the Eve V 2in1 laptop

Answer (score 2):

Windows never "enters BIOS" - the setup utility is invoked before Windows starts, so there is no way to influence it.
With UEFI this may be different, it is up to the UEFI implementation if it allows an OS to request a boot into the setup utility.

Maybe you are asking the wrong question - what stops you from setting up GRUB to have Ubuntu as the default choice? Or just display the boot menu for a long time?

Comment: I formulated my question wrong then, because I don't know what happens on start-up. What I want is instead of Windows starting to have the BIOS to pop-up, so I can choose the OS - is this doable? I tried setting up GRUB so that Ubuntu gets loaded, but without a success. "Or just display the boot menu for a long time?" - maybe that's the reason why the comnination `fn+F7` doesn't work

Comment: Try one of the boot loader applications that are available as that may help you.   https://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/multi-boot-managers.shtml

Comment: @John thanks, is there no way to make the bios to pop-up at start up? I had previously a dual partiticion Windows and Ubuntu and Grub was poping-up asking which OS to load

Comment: No way to start BIOS at startup - that I why I suggest a boot application

Answer (score 1):

Each physical machine is different in the way it starts BIOS. You need to use the method prescribed by your machine.  By default on any machine I have used, BIOS does NOT start automatically - only by considered action on the part of the user.